# d3 cluster-scatterplot - callback d attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript

I want to render a cluster-scatterplot with d3. Each datapoint should have a different symbol, depending on which cluster it belongs to.

```
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(mds)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("transform", (d, i) -> "translate(" + xMap(d) + "," + yMap(d) + ")")
        .attr("d", get_symbol(0))
        .attr("fill", (d, i) -> "#f00")

get_symbol = (i) -> d3.svg.symbol().type(d3.svg.symbolTypes[i]).size(80)
```

This is working so far. I have a function get_cluster(i) that gets me the cluster number the element belongs to. But when I change the line

```
        .attr("d", get_symbol(0))
```

to

```
        .attr("d", (d, i) -> get_symbol(get_cluster(i)))
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="function n(n,r){return(zl.get(t.call(this,n,r))||Oo)(e.call(this,n,r))}"
```

The problem is not the get_cluster function, I still get the error when i write

```
        .attr("d", (d, i) -> get_symbol(0))
```

Why can i pass a callback to all the attr()-functions, but not this one?

Comment: What does the complied JS look like? Can you post that? It looks like the function is not being invoked...

Comment: I don't know how it works in Coffee script but you need to have and immediately invoked function expression to return the accessor, like `(function (i) {return function(d, i) {...}})()`

Comment: js output available here: https://gist.github.com/buesing/1ee3ec078d98f23a8a63

Comment: Cool Blue, I'm not sure how you mean that. Could you post code (js or coffee doesn't matter) that would work in my example?

Comment: Is the code in the link the version that errors? It looks like the one that is ok...

Comment: No, that code produces the error.

Comment: Yes, it looks ok to me... the error indicates that d3 is returning a reference to a callback, somewhere in the selection.attr code (probably in selection.each actually), instead of executing the callback.  I would use the un-minified version of d3 and trace it through in the browser tools to investigate. Have you tried it in different browsers by the way?